# Laravel show product page link on a dynamic navbar

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I'm currently new to laravel, I tried to create a navbar with 3 categories (shirt with cat_id=8), (pant with cat_id=9) and (dress with cat_id=10).

I have products table and categories table connected through `cat_id` column in both tables.

I'm trying to make that when user click on the product link under the category, it will leave it to that product view with it own `pro_id`.

Here is my controller with variable for the main page

```
 public function index()
    {
        $pro_shirt=Products::where('cat_id','8')->get();
        $pro_pant=Products::where('cat_id','9')->get();
        $pro_dress=Products::where('cat_id','10')->get();
        return view('front.home',compact('pro_shirt','pro_pant','pro_dress'));
    }
```

and here my route for that product page link

```
Route::get('/product/{id}',['as' => 'front.product.show', 'uses' => 'HomeController@product']);
```

the controller function for that product page

```
   public function product($id){
        $product = Products::where('pro_id',$id)->Paginate(1);
        return view('front.product.product', compact('product'));
    }
```

and here is my navbar in the blade master view

```
<div class="col1">
                                    <div class="h_nav">
                                        <a href="{{route('front.category.show', ['id' =>8]) }}"><h4>Shirt</h4></a>
                                        <ul>
                                        @foreach($pro_shirt as $shirt)
                                              <li><a href="{{route('front.product.show'),['id' =>$shirt->pro_id]}}">{{$shirt->pro_title}}</a></li>
                                        @endforeach
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col1">
                                    <div class="h_nav">
                                        <a href="{{route('front.category.show', ['id' =>9]) }}"><h4>Pant</h4></a>
                                        <ul>
                                        @foreach($pro_pant as $pant)
                                              <li><a href="{{route('front.product.show'),['id' =>$pant->pro_id]}}">{{$pant->pro_title}}</a></li>
                                        @endforeach
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col1">
                                    <div class="h_nav">
                                        <a href="{{route('front.category.show', ['id' =>10]) }}"><h4>Dress</h4></a>
                                        <ul>
                                        @foreach($pro_dress as $dress)
                                              <li><a href="{{route('front.product.show'),['id' =>$dress->pro_id]}}">{{$dress->pro_title}}</a></li>
                                        @endforeach
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

When I try to click on each product link it show an error:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: front.product.show] [URI: product/{id}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\webshop\resources\views\front\extends\master.blade.php)

I don't know why the pro_id of that product doesn't show but the pro_title showed

UPDATE: I missed a closing `)` in the route so the navbar works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistake in your view,
instead of `{{route('front.product.show'),['id' =>$shirt->pro_id]}}` need
`{{route('front.product.show',['id' =>$shirt->pro_id])}}`.
Do the same for the rest of routes `front.product.show`.

Comment: OMG it worked now thank you :D , i guess my eyes are tired when typing that :D.